# Select múltiplo em Python e Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

Eu tenho uma classe `Lancamento` e uma classe `Plano de conta`. `Plano de conta` é uma chave secundária de Lançamento, ou seja, eu cadastro planos de conta e ao cadastrar um lançamento eu seleciono um plano de conta.

Para isso, fiz assim

```
class Lancamento(models.Model):
    plano = models.ForeignKey(
        PlanoConta,
        related_name="plano",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
```

na classe `LancamentoForm` em `widgets` fiz assim:

```
'plano': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
```

Dessa forma consigo selecionar **um** plano de conta para cada lançamento.
Mas como eu faço para escolher **múltiplos** planos de conta para cada lançamento?

Ao mudar o `forms.Select` para `forms.SelectMultiple` ao tentar selecionar e enviar, obtenho a mensagem **Faça uma escolha válida. Sua escolha não é uma das disponíveis.**